# Flutter Firestore Logical OR best practice

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

**Cloud Firestore does not support Logical OR (||)** , rather it supports IN operator. But I'm handling the Logical OR(||) query in this way. So, Is it a good way to handle it in this way? I would like to know the best practice. As I believe there can be performance issues when we will be having millions of documents. So please let me know what can be the best way to handle it

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firestore the query performance depends on the number of documents you request and not on the number of documents you search. It doesn't really matter if you search 10 documents in a collection of 100 documents or in a collection that contains 100 MIL documents, the response time will always be the same.

Regarding the IN operator, there's nothing you should worry about. As long as you are using the number within the maximum limit of ten elements, everything will work perfectly fine.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Already done Voted Up @Alex Mamo . One more thing to ask that the way I'm doing validation is good as shown in picture?

Comment: Yes, why not? If it does the job, that's the way to go ahead.